# How to compare time in different time zone

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Time Zone Id =Eastern Standard Time. 
I have to do some operation at a specific US time(EST)

```
Example:
I want to do an operation between 11:00-11:30( as an input from user)
I stored this time in 2 string
string StartTime="11:00";
String EndTime="11:30";
```

Suppose when I run the program if current time in US falls between this time(StartTime and EndTime) then I have to do the operation else not

I have the current time in US in one string as string UStime="11:25";

```
                DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

                string strTimeZoneId_Newyork = "Eastern Standard Time";
                TimeZoneInfo tZone_Newyork = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strTimeZoneId_Newyork);
                DateTime dt_Time_Newyork = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, tZone_Newyork);
                string strDayOfWeek_Newyork = dt_Time_Newyork.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                string strTime_Newyork = dt_Time_Newyork.ToShortTimeString();
```

But I want to know to compare if 11:25 falls between 11:00-11:30.

**NOTE**: If I use convert to dateTime it will the system date time.
So I want to compare the string. Is this possible? Is there any other alternative for it?

Comment: I don't understand why can't you compare with datetime?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to parse the start time and end time as EST times, then compare the current local time to those EST times. The sample console app does that below. It does an inclusive comparison (time is >= start AND time is <= end), but if you want exclusive you can change it easily yourself. Also, the inputs are parsed as military time, so you'll want to change that if you want support for a localized, 12-hour format.

The meat of it is the `TryParseTimeAsEst` method, which parses the input, calculates the current offset relative to EST (and including current DST setting), and constructs a `DateTimeOffset` in the correct destination offset.

Please note that .NET will not automatically reflect current DST when you retrieve a `TimeZoneInfo`. The offset will always be the default offset (-5:00 for EST, regardless of the current DST... which at the moment is -4:00). To solve that, you need to get the current time as UTC, and use the `GetUtcOffset` method to get the actual offset w/ DST.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTimeOffset startTime, endTime, current = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Start Time (in Eastern Standard Time)");

        var inputStartTime = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the End Time (in Eastern Standard Time)");

        var inputEndTime = Console.ReadLine();


        if (!TryParseTimeAsEst(inputStartTime, out startTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start time is invalid");
            return;
        }

        if (!TryParseTimeAsEst(inputEndTime, out endTime))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End time is invalid");
            return;
        }

        var currentUtc = current.UtcDateTime;

        if (startTime.UtcDateTime <= ccurrentUtc && currentUtc <= endTime.UtcDateTime)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is between {1} and {2}", current, startTime, endTime);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is NOT between {1} and {2}", current, startTime, endTime);
        }

    }

    static bool TryParseTimeAsEst(string value, out DateTimeOffset time)
    {
        var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        var today = DateTime.Today;
        var nowUtc = DateTime.UtcNow; // need this to generate the offset that respects DST

        try
        {
            var t = TimeSpan.Parse(value); // parse the input into time
            time = new DateTimeOffset(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds, est.GetUtcOffset(nowUtc)); // create a datetime with offset that reflects DST

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            time = DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```